# NSClickGestureRecognizer.location(in:) and hitTest()

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, hittest, nsclickgesturerecognizer

I have the following view:

[image: Screenshot]

which has a custom class based on `NSVisualEffectView`, and contains an image view, a label (`NSTextField`) and a popup button. `isFlipped` of the custom view is always `false`.

The custom view also contains a `NSClickGestureRecognizer` which uses a delegate. The delegate implements just one method:

```
func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: NSGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    let thePoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: view)

    if let theView = view.hitTest(thePoint) {
        return !theView.handlesMouseEvents
    }
    else {
        return true
    }
}
```

If I click in the middle of the popup menu, `location(in:)` returns the value (182, 16) for instance. This seems correct for me for a non-flipped view. But `hitTest()` returns the background view for that point as result and not the popup button.

What am I doing wrong?

If I use the manually flipped point (`y := height - y`) for hit-testing I get the popup button as result. But I don't want to use that approach because it seems ugly to me.

If seems to work if I use the window's content view for hit-testing. But I would still like to know why the approach shown does not work.

Comment: From the documentation of `hitTest(_:)`: "Parameters: aPoint: A point that is in the coordinate system of the view’s superview, not of the view itself.". Is the superview of `view` flipped?

Comment: @Willeke: Thanks for the hint. I've extrapolated from `UIView`. Reading the docs is sometimes useful. ;) If I use `view.superview` for `location(in:)` everything works as expected. Would you convert your comment to an appropriate answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter `point` of `hitTest(_:)` is

> A point that is in the coordinate system of the view’s superview, not of the view itself.

Solution: pass a point in superview coordinates.